# how i can print some array in echo string

Tags: php

i extract som html information of a website using file_get_contents and i want ti print by echo

how i can do

```
$page = file_get_contents('*******');
preg_match("/<span class=\"a-text-strike\".*span>/", $page, $precio_antes);
preg_match("/<span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\".*span>/", $page, $precio_ahora);
preg_match("/<td class=\"a-span12 a-color-price a-size-base\".*td>/", $page, $precio_descuento);

echo "Antes: ".$precio_antes. "Ahora: " .$precio_ahora." (-" .$precio_descuento. "%)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the regular expressions a bit because you will not always get the expected results:

- Make the `.*` lazy, otherwise it will skip some closing `</span>` tags and go right to the last one: `.*?`;
- Make the `.` also match newlines, otherwise matches will fail to find anything if the opening and closing tags are not on the same line: use the `s` pattern modifier;
- As tags can be nested, make sure to test on the ending tag, including the slash: `/span>` instead  of just `span>`;
- The result in the third argument of `preg_match` [is an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), so you need to take the element of your interest: `[0]`

Adapted Code:

```
preg_match("/<span\s+class=\"a-text-strike\".*?\/span>/si", $page, $precio_antes);
preg_match("/<span\s+id=\"priceblock_ourprice\".*?\/span>/si", $page, $precio_ahora);
preg_match("/<td\s+class=\"a-span12\s+a-color-price\s+a-size-base\".*?\/td>/si", $page, $precio_descuento);


echo "Antes: {$precio_antes[0]} Ahora: {$precio_ahora[0]} (-{$precio_descuento[0])}";
```

#### Parse the DOM

Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not advised in general. There will always be cases where it goes wrong because the provider changed the order of attributes, or replaced the double quotes by single quotes, ... etc. You really should have a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

$precio_descuento is array so

Not `$precio_descuento` but `$precio_descuento[0]`

or `implode('', $precio_descuento)`

ps: the same with others